# openacc declare issue with pow function in C++ within acc compute region

Tags: openacc

I'm trying to use openACC to accelerate some of my code. One portion of the code used pow() function from standard library. However there is an error during compilation

PGCC-S-0155-Procedures called in a compute region must have acc routine information: pow

I've roughly know that I need to declare the #pragma acc routine seq in order to remove such type of error. But as I understand this need to be added in the source code of the function(I might be wrong). So how can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `accelmath.h`, instead of `cmath.h`